# How can i get metadata before image will be saved?

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, android-camera2

I work with Camera 2 API and I need get image metadata(exactly ISO) before image will be saved on device.

At this moment I am using `ExifInterface` , but constructor of this class get only `File` or begin from api24 `InputStream`.

How I can get ISO from image before it will be saved?

**EDIT**

```
private final ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener mOnImageAvailableListener
        = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {

    @Override
    public void onImageAvailable(final ImageReader reader) {

        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                new ImageSaver(context, reader.acquireNextImage()).writeImageToStorage();
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
};

public final class ImageSaver {
private Context context;
private static File imageFile;
private final Image image;

public ImageSaver(Context context, Image image) {
    this.context = context;
    this.image = image;
    imageFile = getImageFile(UtilClass.getAvatarPhotosDirFile(context));
}

private File getImageFile(File path) {
    return new File(path.getPath() + File.separator + getStamp() + ".jpeg");
}

public void writeImageToStorage() {
    final ByteBuffer buffer = getByteBuffer();
    final byte[] bytes = getBytes(buffer);
    writeFile(imageFile, bytes);
}

@Nullable
private ByteBuffer getByteBuffer() {
    ByteBuffer buffer = null;
    if (image != null) {
        buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
    }
    return buffer;
}

private byte[] getBytes(ByteBuffer buffer) {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[0];
    if (buffer != null) {
        bytes = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
    }
    if (buffer != null) {
        buffer.get(bytes);
    }
    return bytes;
}

private void writeFile(File file, byte[] bytes) {
    BufferedOutputStream bos = null;

    try {
        bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
        bos.write(bytes);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (image != null) {
            image.close();
        }
        if (null != bos) {
            try {
                bos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

@NonNull
private String getStamp() {

    final int pictureAmount = PreferencesHelper.getIntShared(context, States.PICTURE_AMOUNT) + 1;
    String stamp;

    switch (pictureAmount){
        case 1:
            stamp = "pose1";
            break;
        case 2:
            stamp = "pose3";
            break;
        case 3:
            stamp = "pose5";
            break;
        case 4:
            stamp = "pose7";
            break;
        default:
            stamp = "BG";
            break;
    }
    return stamp;
}

public static String getImageFilePath() {
    return imageFile.getPath();
}

}
```

Comment: You could show how and where you get that image. In which form? And how you save it.

Comment: Much too vague. Please also show how you save an `Image` to file. Are you sure the file contains an Exif if you do so? What is a usual file? And where is the Exif in the Image? How could it contain one?

Comment: @greenapps added . Yes i am sure that file  contains an Exif . How do you think is it possible to solve this issue?

Comment: As you have seen `image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();` contains a jpg file. You can do with it what you want before saving to disk.

Comment: @greenapps ok, but how can i get metadata from it? I thought that i should use `ExifInterface`, but it get on constructor only `String`, `FileDescriptor` or `InputStream`... I have tried to got In What i have to do with `InputStream` but it only available start from api 24... It is the issue

Comment: Cannot you use a ByteArrayInputStream as inputStream for the jpg bytes?

Comment: `ByteArrayinputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);`

Comment: @greenapps yes, of course, but as i said issue is if i use `byte[]` as a param of `ExifInterface` it is available ONLY from api 24 and newer... I use api 21... Have you got my point of view?

Comment: You should use `bais` as parameter of course.

Comment: For the rest you better use a different Exifinterface class. Your problem has been discussed before several times on stackoverflow.

Comment: @greenapps sorry it is my misspoke i mean that i can't put `InputStream` as a param of `ExifInterface`  because of it is required api 24... I use api 21 and only `String filename` could be applicable as a param of `ExifInterface`

Comment: @greenapps could you please build your simple sample and publish it as a answer? Maybe i just don't understand your point of view...

Answer (score 0):

```
ByteArrayinputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
```

Where `bytes` contains a jpeg.

Use `bais` as `InputStream` for a new ExifInterface for Android 7.0.

Else use a different Exifinterface class. There is more than one.

Comment: yes i understood you correct. If i had Android 7.0 i would not ask a question here... but i have Android 6.0 as i have already said... As far as i know there is only one class that give access to image meta... anyway thanks!